# MVC6 Identity Custom Field Retrieval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have added a new column called `CompanyName` to my `AspNetUsers` table. I'm looking to use this in queries within my API.

I have used the `[Authorized]` attribute to get

```
User.Identity.Name
```

This obviously gets the name of the user. I'm looking for a way to get the `CompanyName`.

Will I have to query the `aspnetusers` table directly to get this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your user in order to access user's properties, I use the UserManager class to create the user. There may be other ways to to get this done however this is what I have done in the past.

at the top of the controller class:

```
private Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<YourApplication.Models.ApplicationUser> um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));//new up a UserManager
```

now inside the action method:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        ApplicationUser user = um.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());//Create an instance of the user
        ViewBag.CompanyName = user.CompanyName ;//Read the property
        return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following way will help you to put [custom data](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/custom-membershipprovider-principal-and-identity.html).
if this doesnt help, please provide more information. like the source code of where you create or where you retrieve it.

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
var identity = new MyIdentity(username, true);
var principal = new MyPrincipal(identity, identity.Roles);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```